# Merge K sorted arrays using Heap

Tags: c++, heap

I have written this code but getting compilation error and unable to spot it. Code Explanation:
One class stores data and X axis and Y axis address. 2nd Class is created just to make Functor.
In main I'm creating a MinHeap of size K and after that I pop the minimum element and store it in final answer:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;
class HeapNode{
    public:
        long long int data;
        int addressX;
        int addressY;
        HeapNode(long long int  d,int aX,int aY){
            data=d;
            addressX=aX;
            addressY=aY;
        }
};
class NodeCompare{
    public:
        bool operator()(HeapNode A,HeapNode B){
            return A.data<B.data;
        }
};
int main() {
    int n,k;
    cin>>k>>n;
    long long arr[k][n];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>arr[i][j];
    }
    int i=0;
    vector <long long int> ans;
    ans.reserve(n*k);
    priority_queue<HeapNode,vector<HeapNode>,greater<NodeCompare>> pq;
    for(int j=0;j<k;j++){
            HeapNode H(arr[j][i],j,i);
            pq.push(H);
        }
        HeapNode check=pq.top();
    while(check.data!=INT_MAX){
        HeapNode temp=pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        ans[i]=temp.data;
        i++;
        int x=temp.addressX;
        int y=temp.addressY + 1;
        if(y==n-1){
            HeapNode inp(INT_MAX,x,y);
             pq.push(inp);
        }else{
            HeapNode inp(arr[x][y+1],x,y);
        pq.push(inp);
       } check=pq.top();
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<n*k){
        cout<<ans[i]<<" ";
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error is:

> Compiling failed with exitcode 1, compiler output: In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0, from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39, from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40, from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38, from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39, from prog.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx –

Comment: What kind of compilation error? Post it here please.

Comment: Compiling failed with exitcode 1, compiler output:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx

Comment: I'm not that into compare classes, but have you tried changing `priority_queue<HeapNode,vector<HeapNode>,greater<NodeCompare>>` to `priority_queue<HeapNode,vector<HeapNode>,NodeCompare>`? Maybe this fixes it? So just leave away the greater. Since `NodeCompare` already implements the compare method is should be your compare class, otherwise you would want to compare two `NodeCompare` classes with the `std::greater` compare class.